# Identify GSM / LTE antenna plug

Tags: components, identification, gsm, plug

From my GSM provider I have bought a stationary Internet access point from LTE. 
Additionaly I have bought an antenna for it. Unfortunately when I was plugging it together I have damaged the plug. (Mainly because I want the to avoid this strong electrical field close to my workplace for health reason.)

**Question 1:**
Can someone help me to identify this plug. It looks like:
[image]
The outer diameter of the metal cylinder which is inserted is around 3.8 mm.

Based on my googleing, I suspect it is an male MMCX connector or an SMB connector. Can anybody confim this? In electronic catalogs also an impedance is given (e.g. 50 Ohms). What impedance is best for LTE antennas?

**Question 2:**
I'm thinking to extend the cable from currently 1 m to 5m by making an extension cord with male & female connector. Do you expect that the signal quality is strongly affected by this? Any points on which I should take special care here?
For mounting I i intent to follow this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nKLvaCi_TiA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After asking at the supplier i got the information that it is an T9 MIMO plug.